# How to adjust text box size for a form type drop down list?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, qualtrics

I have a form type question where there are drop down list in Qualtrics. I have used the below code for configuring the drop down list and the text boxes are of different sizes. I want all the text boxes in the same size to appear in my form.

Can anyone help me with the code.. where to adjust the text box size in this below code?

```
var that=this.questionId;
var element="<select id='s1'><option ></option><option value='1'>Aerospace and Defense</option><option value='2'>Automotive</option><option value='3'>Banking and Capital Markets</option><option value='4'>Consumer and Retail</option><option value='5'>Energy, Utilities, Oil and Gas</option><option value='6'>Healthcare</option><option value='7'>Insurance</option><option value='8'>Life Sciences</option><option value='9'>Manufacturing</option><option value='10'>Public Sector</option><option value='11'>Technology, Media and Telecommunications</option><option value='12'>Travel, Transportation and Hospitality</option><option value='13'>Life Sciences</option><option value='14'>Other</option></select>";
jQuery(element).insertAfter("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(0)");
var element="<select id='s1'><option ></option><option value='1'>Less than 100</option><option value='2'>101-999</option><option value='3'>1,000-10,000</option><option value='4'>10,000-100,000</option><option value='5'>More than 100,000</option><option value='6'>Unknown</option></select>";
jQuery(element).insertAfter("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(2)");
var element="<select id='s2'><option ></option><option value='1'>Less than 50</option><option value='2'>50-249</option><option value='3'>250-999</option><option value='4'>More than 1000</option><option value='5'>Unknown</option></select>";
jQuery(element).insertAfter("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(3)");
 var element="<select id='s3'><option ></option><option value='1'>Less than 5 million</option><option value='2'>5-10 million</option><option value='3'>10-1 billion</option><option value='4'>More than 1 billion</option><option value='5'>Prefer not to say</option></select>";
jQuery(element).insertAfter("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(4)");
jQuery("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(0)").hide();
jQuery("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(2)").hide();
jQuery("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(3)").hide();
jQuery("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(4)").hide();

    jQuery("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(0)").val(jQuery("#s1 option:selected").text()); 
    jQuery("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(2)").val(jQuery("#s2 option:selected").text());
    jQuery("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(3)").val(jQuery("#s3 option:selected").text());
    jQuery("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(4)").val(jQuery("#s4 option:selected").text());
    
jQuery("#s1").on('change',function(){
    jQuery("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(0)").val(jQuery("#s1 option:selected").text());
});

jQuery("#s1").on('change',function(){
    jQuery("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(2)").val(jQuery("#s2 option:selected").text());
});

    jQuery("#s2").on('change',function(){
    jQuery("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(3)").val(jQuery("#s3 option:selected").text());
});

  jQuery("#s3").on('change',function(){
    jQuery("#"+that+" .InputText:eq(4)").val(jQuery("#s4 option:selected").text());
});
```

});[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW6IQ.png)

Comment: can you add your code to jsfiddle or codepen or any env, where one can debug and provide feedback to you?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below styles for your select field, it should do trick for you

```
    <style>
    select{
        width: <desired_width>;
        height: <desired_height>;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
```